# Why are our Hamcrest assertions not recognized as valid assertions for rule S2699?

Tags: sonarqube

We are running Sonarqube 5.5 with Java Plugin 3.14 and analyze via sonar-maven-plugin version 3.0.2 calling "mvn clean deploy sonar:sonar".

We still get violations "Add at least one assertion to this test case" about missing assertThat when test code contains stuff like the following.

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasSize;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
[...]
@Test
public void testByClassicCompare() throws InvalidPropertiesFormatException {
    final CompareFilter compareFilter = new CompareFilter("gid", 333,    Operation.LT);
    assertThat(findAll(compareFilter), hasSize(1));
}
```

findAll() is a method in the test class. It just calls some hibernate finder and returns a collection of objects:

```
protected Collection<MyObject> findAll(final HbnFilter filter)
```

Update:
When we change the assert to the following, sonar recognizes the assert.

```
    assertThat(findAll(compareFilter).size(), eq(1));
```

Comment: What is the "findAll" method ? Are you analyzing your project with maven ? if not how do you provide bytecode to the analysis ? As there were a lot of improvements done on type inference in version 4.0 of the java plugin (requiring SQ LTS 5.6) would you be able to try on this version ?

Comment: @benzonico I updated the question according to your input. Although the mentioned project is already java 8 we will have to migrate all other projects to java 8 until we can update SQ from 5.5 to 5.6 LTS

Comment: Java 8 is required to run the analyzer and the sonarqube server, but you can still analyze projects that are not java 8.

Comment: Please specify the full signature of the findAll method.

Comment: @benzonico method signature added

Comment: Given the signature, there is method type inference at play. I really recommend you to upgrade.

Comment: We recently updated to 5.6.1 on now it looks a lot better. We'll have to check some details, but most of the assertion issues are gone away. Thanks for help so far.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause here is the using JUnit's assertThat method:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
```

Instead of Hamcrest's one:

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
```

I've recently faced the [problem with the same solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49070436/sonar-complains-about-assertthat-with-nullvalue).