# Sonar complains about assertThat with nullValue

Tags: java, junit, sonarqube, hamcrest

Having the test case using JUnit 4.12:

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.nullValue;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

//...

@Test
public void testShouldReturnNull() {
    final Long result = getIdFunction.apply(null);
    assertThat(result, is(nullValue()));
}
```

Sonar says:

> Add at least one assertion to this test case.

Why does Sonar says that there are no assertions and how it can be fixed?

SonarQube v6.7

Comment: could be that it doesn't recognise the assert signature, have you tried with `assertNull(result);`? which gives a clearer indication of what the result should be

Answer (score 0):

I've just found a solution for this case:

Here should be used assertThat method from Hamcrest's MatcherAssert class instead of JUnit's Assert class. So here should be used next import:

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
```

instead of:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
```